# Where's my USB Disk / Memory Stick

Tags: usb, hard-drive

So, I did a

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

today and it all went smoothly from an installation point of view. My Wi-Fi dongle works much better as well. However, the PI now fails to see the USB memory stick and USB hard drive that it used to be able to see. Doing an

```
lsusb
```

does not list the devices.

Anyone any ideas where the devices have gone and how to get them back. I have been using the standard wheezy build and the only thing I've installed is emacs and the build tools it requires.

I can update with log/configuration files so just leave any requests for further information in the comments.

**Update**

Here's the dmesg log file:-

```
    [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
    [    0.000000] Linux version 3.2.27+ (dc4@dc4-arm-01) (gcc version 4.7.2 20120731 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2458 - Linaro GCC 2012.08) ) #160 PREEMPT Mon Sep 17 23:18:42 BST 2012
    [    0.000000] CPU: ARMv6-compatible processor [410fb767] revision 7 (ARMv7), cr=00c5387d
    [    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache
    [    0.000000] Machine: BCM2708
    [    0.000000] Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
    [    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 49152
    [    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c050d508, node_mem_map c05b5000
    [    0.000000]   Normal zone: 384 pages used for memmap
    [    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
    [    0.000000]   Normal zone: 48768 pages, LIFO batch:15
    [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
    [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
    [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 48768
    [    0.000000] Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1792 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=952 bcm2708.boardrev=0x2 bcm2708.serial=0x3c363e48 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:36:3E:48 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
    [    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
    [    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
    [    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
    [    0.000000] Memory: 192MB = 192MB total
    [    0.000000] Memory: 188980k/188980k available, 7628k reserved, 0K highmem
    [    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
    [    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    [    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xfff00000 - 0xfffe0000   ( 896 kB)
    [    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xcc800000 - 0xe8000000   ( 440 MB)
    [    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xcc000000   ( 192 MB)
    [    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xc0000000   (  16 MB)
    [    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc04c1ec8   (4840 kB)
    [    0.000000]       .init : 0xc04c2000 - 0xc04e1930   ( 127 kB)
    [    0.000000]       .data : 0xc04e2000 - 0xc050dba0   ( 175 kB)
    [    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc050dbc4 - 0xc05b4ae8   ( 668 kB)
    [    0.000000] NR_IRQS:330
    [    0.000000] sched_clock: 32 bits at 1000kHz, resolution 1000ns, wraps every 4294967ms
    [    0.000000] timer_set_mode: unhandled mode:1
    [    0.000000] timer_set_mode: unhandled mode:3
    [    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
    [    0.000000] console [tty1] enabled
    [    0.000938] Calibrating delay loop... 697.95 BogoMIPS (lpj=3489792)
    [    0.060154] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
    [    0.060629] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
    [    0.061115] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
    [    0.061209] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
    [    0.061247] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
    [    0.061277] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
    [    0.061422] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
    [    0.061773] hw perfevents: enabled with v6 PMU driver, 3 counters available
    [    0.062983] devtmpfs: initialized
    [    0.073178] NET: Registered protocol family 16
    [    0.074855] vc_mem_connected_init: called
    [    0.074937] bcm2708_vcio: bcm_mailbox_property failed (-19)
    [    0.074981] vc_mem_update: success=-19 resp 0, vcbase=0 vcsize=0 armbase=0 armsize=0
    [    0.075026] vc-mem: mm_vc_mem_phys_addr = 0x00000000
    [    0.075056] vc-mem: mm_vc_mem_size      = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
    [    0.075535] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
    [    0.075592] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
    [    0.075631] mailbox: Broadcom VideoCore Mailbox driver
    [    0.075726] bcm2708_vcio: mailbox at f200b880
    [    0.075816] bcm_power: Broadcom power driver
    [    0.075855] bcm_power_open() -> 0
    [    0.075880] bcm_power_request(0, 8)
    [    0.576564] bcm_mailbox_read -> 00000080, 0
    [    0.576603] bcm_power_request -> 0
    [    0.576629] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
    [    0.576784] dev:f1: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x20201000 (irq = 83) is a PL011 rev3
    [    0.902846] console [ttyAMA0] enabled
    [    0.927671] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
    [    0.932840] SCSI subsystem initialized
    [    0.936940] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
    [    0.942562] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
    [    0.948193] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
    [    0.954121] Switching to clocksource stc
    [    0.958476] FS-Cache: Loaded
    [    0.961654] CacheFiles: Loaded
    [    0.977852] NET: Registered protocol family 2
    [    0.982773] IP route cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
    [    0.990851] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
    [    0.998368] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
    [    1.005013] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
    [    1.011424] TCP reno registered
    [    1.014590] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
    [    1.020502] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
    [    1.027280] NET: Registered protocol family 1
    [    1.032463] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
    [    1.038594] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
    [    1.043317] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
    [    1.048032] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
    [    1.054788] bcm2708_dma: DMA manager at cc808000
    [    1.059569] bcm2708_gpio: bcm2708_gpio_probe c04e9c18
    [    1.065014] vc-mem: Videocore memory driver
    [    1.070037] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
    [    1.075521] type=2000 audit(0.740:1): initialized
    [    1.192620] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
    [    1.196770] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
    [    1.204357] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
    [    1.210658] msgmni has been set to 369
    [    1.216439] io scheduler noop registered
    [    1.220550] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
    [    1.225858] io scheduler cfq registered
    [    1.261237] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 224x59
    [    1.290725] kgdb: Registered I/O driver kgdboc.
    [    1.304933] brd: module loaded
    [    1.313157] loop: module loaded
    [    1.317228] vcos: [1]: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xffd80000, is_master = 0
    [    1.324945] vcos: [1]: vchiq_init_state: called
    [    1.330431] vcos: [1]: vchiq: initialised - version 2 (min 2), device 252.0
    [    1.338148] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
    [    1.344250] cdc_ncm: 04-Aug-2011
    [    1.347702] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
    [    1.353563] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
    [    1.559771] Core Release: 2.80a
    [    1.563051] Setting default values for core params
    [    1.567992] Finished setting default values for core params
    [    1.773952] Using Buffer DMA mode
    [    1.777384] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
    [    1.783396] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
    [    1.789146] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
    [    1.793624] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
    [    1.797409] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
    [    1.797460] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: DWC OTG Controller
    [    1.802591] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
    [    1.810078] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: irq 32, io mem 0x00000000
    [    1.815759] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
    [    1.819825] Init: Power Port (0)
    [    1.823246] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
    [    1.836527] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    1.849982] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
    [    1.860852] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.2.27+ dwc_otg_hcd
    [    1.873029] usb usb1: SerialNumber: bcm2708_usb
    [    1.884862] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
    [    1.894852] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
    [    1.905762] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
    [    1.905781] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
    [    1.905803] Module dwc_common_port init
    [    1.906161] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
    [    1.917801] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
    [    1.929025] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
    [    1.941245] USB Mass Storage support registered.
    [    1.952358] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
    [    1.964569] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
    [    1.977138] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=700000 max=700000 cur=700000
    [    1.983035] bcm2835-cpufreq: switching to governor powersave
    [    1.994720] bcm2835-cpufreq: switching to governor powersave
    [    2.006841] cpuidle: using governor ladder
    [    2.023306] cpuidle: using governor menu
    [    2.033621] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
    [    2.045825] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
    [    2.056489] sdhci: Enable low-latency mode
    [    2.066807] bcm_power_open() -> 1
    [    2.076365] Registered led device: mmc0::
    [    2.077798] mmc0: SDHCI controller on BCM2708_Arasan [platform] using platform's DMA
    [    2.092066] mmc0: BCM2708 SDHC host at 0x20300000 DMA 2 IRQ 77
    [    2.104338] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
    [    2.116861] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
    [    2.136782] Registered led device: led0
    [    2.137239] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
    [    2.164142] usbhid: USB HID core driver
    [    2.189633] TCP cubic registered
    [    2.208313] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
    [    2.225087] mmc0: problem reading SD Status register.
    [    2.248271] NET: Registered protocol family 17
    [    2.260835] Registering the dns_resolver key type
    [    2.275802] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address b368
    [    2.298337] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 1 part 20 variant b rev 5
    [    2.312997] mmcblk0: mmc0:b368 00000 3.74 GiB 
    [    2.327901]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
    [    2.337000] registered taskstats version 1
    [    2.348533] drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
    [    2.391306] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    [    2.405942] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:2.
    [    2.428432] devtmpfs: mounted
    [    2.438369] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
    [    2.451646] Freeing init memory: 124K
    [    2.461707] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
    [    2.688631] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9512
    [    2.702630] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [    2.717652] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
    [    2.727841] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
    [    3.018517] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
    [    3.128891] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
    [    3.144501] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [    3.165917] smsc95xx v1.0.4
    [    3.243878] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:36:3e:48
    [    3.378552] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
    [    3.518167] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1c4f, idProduct=0002
    [    3.533760] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [    3.547863] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB Keykoard
    [    3.558939] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: USB
    [    3.584371] input: USB USB Keykoard as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input0
    [    3.618521] generic-usb 0003:1C4F:0002.0001: input: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [USB USB Keykoard] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2/input0
    [    3.662677] input: USB USB Keykoard as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/input/input1
    [    3.698449] generic-usb 0003:1C4F:0002.0002: input: USB HID v1.10 Device [USB USB Keykoard] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2/input1
    [    3.828626] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
    [    3.971377] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=07d1, idProduct=3303
    [    4.006769] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [    4.023531] usb 1-1.3: Product: 11n Adapter
    [    4.035923] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Manufacturer Realtek 
    [    4.048829] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
    [    4.291973] udevd[137]: starting version 175
    [    5.288070] r8712u: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
    [    5.587342] r8712u: DriverVersion: v7_0.20100831
    [    5.938446] r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
    [    6.303055] r8712u: USB_SPEED_HIGH with 4 endpoints
    [    6.468308] r8712u: Boot from EFUSE: Autoload OK
    [    7.586105] r8712u: CustomerID = 0x0000
    [    7.597758] r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = 90:94:e4:51:70:99
    [    7.611378] r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
    [    7.627931] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8712u
    [    8.233367] udevd[169]: renamed network interface wlan0 to wlan1
    [   15.031806] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
    [   15.555270] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
    [   16.391252] bcm2835 ALSA card created!
    [   20.256509] Adding 131068k swap on /var/swapfile.  Priority:-1 extents:2 across:425980k SS
    [   21.050479] mmc0: missed completion of cmd 18 DMA (512/512 [1]/[1]) - ignoring it
    [   21.066085] mmc0: DMA IRQ 6 ignored - results were reset
    [   21.088257] mmc0: missed completion of cmd 18 DMA (512/512 [1]/[1]) - ignoring it
    [   21.104193] mmc0: DMA IRQ 6 ignored - results were reset
    [   24.328834] r8712u: 1 RCR=0x153f00e
    [   24.329699] r8712u: 2 RCR=0x553f00e
    [   37.314038] r8712u: [r8712_got_addbareq_event_callback] mac = 00:23:cd:1a:a6:92, seq = 16, tid = 0
```

Comment: How are the missing devices connected to your Pi, and have you rebooted the Pi?

Comment: @SteveRobillard: Via a powered hub and, for test, the USB memory stick directly into the PI. Rebooted (power off at mains) several times. Device not found regardless.

Comment: Any messages in `dmesg`?

Comment: I did look in dmesg but didn't see anything helpful. The mount failed (obviously). I can (hopefully) post the contents of dmesg later if that'll help.

Answer (score 3):

Are you on the edge of the allowable power on the USB hub? If so, the spike of power used by the HDD may cause low enough voltage to cause issues. You may want to try a higher power hub (and power supply).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's been a change somewhere that had created a conflict between the various USB devices that I have connected. These are the devices I have:

- 11n wireless dongle
- Keyboard
- Mouse #
- LaCie HDD #
- Kingston memory stick #
- 7 Port powered hub #

The items marks '#' work well together. Plugging the keyboard into the USB hub causes the two storage devices to vanish, whereas plugging it into the PI itself with the hub in the other port works.

The WiFi dongle has similar problems: when it's in the hub, it has a MAC address of ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff and won't connect to anything (as I've mentioned before) but the storage devices are still present, whereas plugging it into the PI it works fine.

So at the moment it's either storage devices or WiFi. I will try other keyboards and see if they work.

Seems crazy to me that the USB 'standard' can lead to such problems, you'd have thought all the kinks would be ironed out by now. Sigh.

Comment: Did all these devices work together before the update?  Or do you need the update for required drivers for some of the hardware?  Wild idea, but do you think it could be a power issue with your powered hub and all of the devices connected?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn: Well, they all sort of worked together before the update - it required careful timing with switching on the hub during boot up but they did all work. I'll look at the power supply later and see what it's rated at.